# QWidget doesn't close when main window is closed

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm trying to make a main window (QWidget) which open a new QWidget when a button is clicked but when I close the main window, the QWidget recently opened doesn't close.

**main.cpp**

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

**mainwindow.cpp** (parent)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

**out.cpp** (child)

```
Out::Out(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Out)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: They are a lot of lines, i don't know which part I must post.

Comment: I would suggest you write as small an example as possible that reproduces the problem, and post that. But for starters, what does your main.cpp look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose`:

> Makes Qt quit the application when the last widget with the attribute
>   set has accepted closeEvent(). This behavior can be modified with the
>   QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed property. By default this
>   attribute is set for all widgets of type Qt::Window.

In this case, you should probably call:

```
myWidget->setAttribute( Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for Python

Try to create a function like below

```py
def func_quit_all_windows():
  sys.exit()
```

Remember to `import sys`

When the button is clicked call the function

```py
btn.clicked.connect(func_quit_all_windows)
```