# How to make pop up window close automatically after main window is closed

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt4

I am using PyQT to create QMainWindow window that opens another window when a button is clicked. My problem is that the popup window remains displayed even if I close the main window which spawned it. This is very similar with the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468584/qwidget-doesnt-close-when-main-window-is-closed) but written in C++ and I can only do Python. How can I implement the answer in Python? Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

class Pycryptor:

    def mainGui(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        #MainWindow
        self.mainWin = QMainWindow()
        self.mainWin.setGeometry(200,200,500,432)
        self.mainWin.show()
        #MenuBar
        mainMenu = self.mainWin.menuBar()
        mainMenu.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        aboutMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('A&bout')
        helpButton = QAction(QIcon(),'Help',self.mainWin)
        helpButton.triggered.connect(self.helpPopup)
        aboutMenu.addAction(helpButton)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def helpPopup(self):
        self.popup = HelpWindow()
        self.popup.setGeometry(800,200,300,500)
        self.popup.show()

class HelpWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pycryptor()
    p.mainGui()
```

Comment: HelpWindow object setParent MainWindow

Comment: I'm sorry can you show me how to do it? I'm just starting to learn about classes

Answer (score 1):

in c++ you can setParent your widget object a mainWindow object. When the parent will be destroyed he will follow all his children.

**for example:**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Form *fm = new Form();
    fm->setParent(this);
    fm->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    fm->show();
}
```

i dont know hot to create this pyqt but you can read documentation:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setParent